# Connecting python to MySQL workbench?

Tags: python, sql

I am new to Data Analytics and the tools used. I have vague background knowledge on Python, MySQLWorkbench, Tableau. Currently, I am taking a course on data and have a final project. Currently, I am attempting to connect my python to excel file to MySqlWorkbench. Has anyone done this before or know how to connect. I have posted my script for reference.

```
import pandas as pd
import xlrd
import MySQLdb
import sqlalchemy


#Adding own column names
user_columns = ['RowID','OrderID','OrderDate','OrderPriority','OrderQuantity','Sales','Discount','ShipMode','Profit','UnitPrice','ShippingCost','CustomerName','Province','Region','CustomerSegment', 'ProductCategory','ProductSubCategory','ProductName','ProductContainer','ProductBaseMargin','ShipDate']
barget = pd.read_excel('/Users/CreativeInnovations/Documents/colaberry/pythonClass/Externalscripts/Barget_Store.xls', sep=',', header=None,names=user_columns)

engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine('mysql+mysqldb://root:The51014@Localhost/Barget')
barget.to_sql('barget', engine,if_exists='replace')
```

Comment: next time use button `{}` to correctly format code on SO.

Comment: do you get error message or what ? Always put in question full error message (Traceback).